# How to mark success for the failed task in Apache Airflow using Google Cloud Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Google Cloud Composer for Apache Airflow. Trying to mark success to one of the failed job, But it is giving "Exception: Ooops" error.

When I am trying from UI, DAG page. It is not giving any instance of job which needs to be marked as success. But when I see from ( browse >> Tasks Instances ), I can see Failed tasks. 
[No tasks being listed down when trying to mark the failed job as success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q13WL.jpg)

And when I go to ( browse >> Tasks Instances ), Select the failed instances, and try to (With Selected >> Set state to success). It is giving Oops Exception.

How to mark the failed job as success in Airflow, So predecessor can be triggered?

Comment: This issue is not coming in latest GCP Composer image and I am able to mark the job as success